# Local master branch out of tune from remote master

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, gitbox

Here is what has happened

In master local branch .. I did a merge with mtv branch

```
git merge mtv
```

There were conflicts, I merged those and see the modification in my gitbox.

I did not commit but somehow, I have no idea what button was pushed, it appears my local master branch seemed to have been rebased or something, infact local master has the code that I wanted. I see the changes of 'mtv' branch there and looks like all is good. BUT git push gives me the conflicts again, I must have done something weird and remote master might have been confused. Please help how to address this issue. I planned to unpublish then publish master - or - rename remote master and publish local master. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

What conflicts does it show? If you are using a tool, it is probably doing a git pull before doing a git push and that is what is causing the issue. If you can help it always use a terminal to run git commands.